# How to revert file back before git add

Tags: git, version-control

I have made some changes to file but didn't do `git add .`

how can i revert back changes to last commit?

I do not want to loose my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git reset --hard` will discard changes to all *tracked* files in both your working directory and the index, restoring both of them to match the state of the currently-checked-out commit.

`git checkout PATH` will copy the file `PATH` from the index to the working directory, and is a suitable way to revert local changes to a single file if you have not yet added the changed version to the index with `git add`.  If you have done `git add` then you can use `git checkout HEAD -- PATH` (replacing only `PATH` with the path to the file in question) to copy the file from the currently-checked-out commit instead of the index.

`git clean -fd` will remove (non-ignored) *untracked* files from your working directory.

You can combine `reset` and `clean` to completely remove all local changes, restoring the state of your working directory to exactly what is in the currently-checked-out commit, including removing all untracked files, even those you have added to `.gitignore`, like so: `git reset --hard && git clean -fdx`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `git log --follow [file]` to find the version of the file you want (shows your commits). Find the commit you want, and use `git reset --hard [commmit]` to discard all history after specified commit.